# Kotlin android spinner problems

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I am using Kotlin, and I am having some problems with my spinner. Why don't I have any errors and it doesn't work? My items are in the strings.xml.

```
var text = spinner.selectedItem.toString()

if (text == "Item1") {
    textview2.setText("Item1").toString()
}

if (text == "Item2") {
    textview2.setText("Item2").toString()
}

if (text == "Item3") {
    textview2.setText("Item3").toString()
}
```

Comment: Please post full code.

Comment: need more details. are you sure that your `text` object is not null ? You should try to debug it : use log for checking the value for `text` . And for the evaluation part, you should use `when` with `else`, instead of multiple `if` I think.